# part of speech: a very youthful 65?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I saw the following sentence:

> She's a very youthful 65.

It seems "65" is a countable noun, but can we say "She's a 65"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You saw that sentence [**where**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)?

Answer (score 3):

No - it's not idiomatic to say *She's a 65*, and I don't think it's particularly meaningful to say ***65*** is a "countable noun" in the cited context.

But it *is* useful to think of the usage as implying there are *many different ways of being 65* - one/some of which look younger than you might expect from the number of years. Effectively, we're being invited to think of "youthful appearance" as being an attribute of *some examples of [people at the age of] 65*. You could compare this usage to...

> *It was **a chastened Emmanuel Macron** who addressed the French nation on December 10th*
>    <sub>[*The Economist,* Dec 11th 2018](https://www.economist.com/europe/2018/12/11/macron-tries-to-buy-off-his-critics)</sub>

...where the implication is there are different "manifestations" of Macron - and one he showed in that national address was a chastened / apologetic "version" of himself. And for another version based entirely on *numbers*, I found...

> *Many a woman is **a perfect 36-24-36***
>     <sub>[*The Comic Encyclopedia* (1978)*,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Many%20a%20woman%20is%20a%20perfect%2036%2024%2036%22)</sub>

(Where those numbers represent the idealised "hourglass" figure for a woman, expressed as bust-waist-hip measurements in inches.)

One key point about this usage is that there *must* be some kind of ***adjectival*** element before the "head noun" *(65, Emmanuel Macron, 36-24-36)*, to distinguish the version being referred to from *other* instances of those "nouns" that *don't* have the adjectivally-specified quality.

*Unless* it makes sense to interpret the head noun as a short form of something else. Which works with *a 36-24-36 = a 36-24-36 **figure***, but not really with *a 65 = **a 65-year-old*** - and there's simply no way to do this with *Emmanuel Macron*.

---

As regards "parts of speech", I don't think that's a very useful concept in contexts like this. But given the article *(**a** youthful 65)*, if you feel you *must* assign some kind of label, it could only be classified as a ***noun phrase***.

---

You might find the ELU question [*Why is it “a defeated Napoleon”, not “the defeated Napoleon” who rode off the battlefield and into exile?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42645/why-is-it-a-defeated-napoleon-not-the-defeated-napoleon-who-rode-off-the-bat) useful. Note that the usage is fairly unlikely in colloquial speech - it's a literary/oratorial device, that you're actually more likely to find in newspapers and magazine articles today.

Comment: Does "He is an astonishing 8 feet tall" sound OK?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say it ***looks*** (or ***reads***) okay. This kind of  oratorical device isn't common in natural ***speech***.

Comment: Are you saying "a 65-year-old" is incorrect?

Comment: +1 Hubb-a Hubb-a dude.  a-vatar.

Comment: "*One key point about this usage is that there must be some kind of adjectival element before the "head noun"*. Up to this point, your answer was **a ten** in my book.

Comment: @Chemomechanics: Fair point. When I started the answer I had a pretty clear picture of what I was going to say, but I can't deny it started to unravel a bit when I got down to the detailed level of *Exactly how does the presence/abscence of an **adjective** affect idiomacy?* How come "adjective-less" *She's a 10* and *She's a 36-24-36* are more-or-less okay in many contexts, but *She's a 65* would almost never pass muster? That was just too complicated for me to address properly in what was already becoming a fairly long answer.

Answer (score 1):

*She's a 65* would mean:

- she is literally the number 65.
- she is rated a 65 in some sort of contest or evaluation.

It may help if you think of *She's 65* as short for *She's 65 years old*.

Answer (score 1):

There's 65 ... and there's 65.  There's a decrepit 65 and a spry 65.

"countable" is such a crappy way of labeling the phenomenon. **a** can be an *individuation* or *sampling* marker.

Each adjective creates a subset of 65.  **a** culls a member of the subset.

Comment: Not sure about ***a** culls a member of the subset*. Perhaps it would be more accurate to say ***a** identifies/selects a single member of **that** subset* .